# Реализация SFML.System.Clock в C# и последующая ошибка при использовании таймера

Tags: c#, .net, sfml

Исходный код:

```
public void Start()
{
    IntPtr AdofaiWindow = FindWindow(null, "A Dance of Fire and Ice");
    if (SetForegroundWindow(AdofaiWindow))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
        TimeInMsList[0] = 2200;
        string backKey = @"\";
        int totalTime = 0;
        var timer = new SFML.System.Clock();
        timer.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < TimeInMsList.Length; i++)
        {
            totalTime += (int)TimeInMsList[i];
            while (timer.ElapsedTime.AsMicroseconds() < totalTime) ;
            SendKeys.SendWait(backKey);
            if (backKey == @"\")
                backKey = "e";
            else backKey = @"\";
        }
        SendKeys.SendWait(backKey);
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что при использовании таймера я вижу следующую ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение: System.DllNotFoundException: Не удается загрузить DLL "csfml-system": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
> в SFML.System.Clock.sfClock_create()
> в SFML.System.Clock..ctor()
> в Adofai_Macros.ReleaseKey.Start() в C:\Users\zimer\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\My Projects\Adofai Macros\Adofai Macros\ReleaseKey.cs:строка 35
> в Adofai_Macros.Program.Main() в C:\Users\zimer\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\My Projects\Adofai Macros\Adofai Macros\Program.cs:строка 20
> Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Каким образом я установил SFML?
Я нажал на "Проект" >> "Управление пакетами NuGet", далее установил SFML.NET.
В проекте есть ссылки на библиотеки(.dll в проекте есть)
Чем может быть вызвана эта ошибка? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Попробуйте не `Any CPU`, а `x32` или `x64`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это не привело до нужного результата. ошибка возникает так же